# Which Fields do I need to Index?

Tags: mysql

When I run a query:

```
select categories.name as CatName, items.name as ItemName, item_options.price as Price from categories
left join items on categories.id = items.category_id
left join item_options on items.id = item_options.item_id
Where categories.takeawayID = 55276
```

It take too long to get the result: 273 rows in set (3 min 14.56 sec)

It look like I need add index on the fields? but which one?

I try adding EXPLAIN with the SELECT query, I dont understand what it mean:

```
mysql> Explain select categories.name as CatName, items.name as ItemName, item_options.price as Price from categories
    -> left join items on categories.id = items.category_id
    -> left join item_options on items.id = item_options.item_id
    -> Where categories.takeawayID = 55276;
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys                             | key           | key_len | ref                   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories   | ALL  | NULL                                      | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                  |  14086 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | items        | ref  | category_id_2,category_id_3,category_id_4 | category_id_2 | 4       | menu.categories.id    |      9 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | item_options | ALL  | NULL                                      | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                  | 197401 |             |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: WAIT... the server crashes? I doubt that's an index issue. Regardin your OP you should add indexes to categories.id and item_options.item_id

Comment: You right, it didnt crash.... 273 rows in set (3 min 14.56 sec)

Comment: Add the 2 indexes then [optimize tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html). Then tell me the result ^^

Comment: OK will do but why did you not choose items.category_id to index?

Comment: Shrugs, saw it has possible keys, figured you already did that!

Comment: Result: 273 rows in set (0.02 sec).. thanks it worked! Why did you say index item_options.item_id (it didnt say in Explain?)

Comment: You use it `left join item_options on items.id = item_options.item_id` here. Meaning you could take advantage from it, especially considering that table has `197401` rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should add indexes on anything that is in a `join`, `where`, `group by` or `order by` section.

This generally means everything that has `id` in the name should get an index.